# Sending user to a new page after submission

Tags: spring-boot

After submitting a new Episode entity I need my user to be sent back to the dashboard - ie /dashboard

I have tried

```
return /dashboard
```

but that simply sent the template to the browser without any data.

My controller looks like this:

```
public class formController {

private EpisodeRepository episodeRepository;

@Autowired
public void setEpisodeRepository(EpisodeRepository episodeRepository) {
    this.episodeRepository = episodeRepository;
}

@GetMapping("/newEpisode")
public String episodeForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("episode", new Episode());
    return "episode";
}

@PostMapping("/newEpisode")
public String episodeSubmit(@ModelAttribute Episode episode) {
    episodeRepository.save(episode);
    return "dashboard";
}

@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public String dashboard(Model model) {
    List<Episode>listEpisodes = new ArrayList<>();
    episodeRepository.findAll().forEach((episode) -> {
        listEpisodes.add(episode);
            });
    System.out.println(listEpisodes.size());
    model.addAttribute("episodes", listEpisodes);
    return "dashboard";
}

@GetMapping("/event/{eventno}")
public String findEvent(@PathVariable String eventno, Model model) {
    Episode episode = new Episode();
    episode = episodeRepository.findByeventno(eventno);
    System.out.println("Printing the values held in episode for one get: " +eventno);
    model.addAttribute("episode", episode);
    return "episode";
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of the html

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/newEpisode}" th:object="${episode}">
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is:

```
    @PostMapping("newEpisode")
public String episodeSubmit(@ModelAttribute Episode episode) {
    episodeRepository.save(episode);
    return "redirect:/dashboard";
}
```